# Create Migration based on current SQL Server schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

Our development team was handed an ASP.NET MVC C# web application from a vendor that has been poorly built and maintained over the years. It started with code first migrations but at some point in time changes were made to the database that were not done with a migration. Now we have a production database with mismatched migrations. My question now, does anyone know of a way to create a migration from the current schema? Kind of like a reverse migration, take the current schema, and create a code first migration for its current state.

If not, open to suggestions as to what steps should be taken to get the migrations to match up with the current production database.

Comment: What is the end goal? A migration is a means to an end, not the end itself.

Comment: If the objective is to make the database consistently deployable, then you could use a database project to manage the database schema instead of using code first. (database first)

Comment: The end goal is to have migrations that can create the current production database consistently. Whereas right now, running the migrations will create a database different than what the current live version is due to the changes made outside of migrations.

Comment: Im not familiar with database projects? Id prefer to use the EF Code first since we already have some implemented just not the complete schema

Comment: If the database was changed, the schema stuff should be reflected in the model classes. Stored procs, indices, etc would not be. So first, try a migration and see what it generates. It will either be the complete schema, meaning it is not comparing correctly to the last migration or the __MigrationHistory table is not present. If the prior migrations and __MigrationHistory table are present and the context key still matches it would generate a migration with just the updates.

Comment: If that does not work, reset the migrations by removing the table, deleting the old code migrations and then adding a new baseline migration whose sole purpose is to take a snapshot of the current state. `add-migration NewBaseline -IgnoreChanges` (EF6 syntax). Now subsequent migrations will just contain the differences.

Comment: @SteveGreene ^^ I like that Idea. Im not too set on keeping a migration history thats incorrect. So I could certainly try that route and see if the application still works from that approach.

Comment: It is not really about the app working. It's about getting older databases up-to-date. If you had to, you could do a schema compare to get them in sync. Depends on how many databases and what their DB state is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being deleting all previous old migrations, adding a new migration based on current model schema and starting fresh from there. There were still some discrepancies we saw with the production database, like new foreign keys, and lost indexes. But it was a good place to start, and now allows us to spin up the database and run our seeders in new environments.